# UIScrollView scroll by specific point

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains multiple UITableViews in it. The design is I have the UIScrollView to be the width of the view which is 320. The tableViews to be offset from the left with 10 pts and a width of 280, in which the next UITableView should be shown (or previewed) with 20 pts being shown.

[image: UIScrollView]

I want that when I scroll the UIScrollView, it would only move by 290. Is there a method available for this in iOS or I would need a calculation to adjust the contentSize of the UIScrollView

Comment: Your scrollview is horizontal with some `UITableView`s inside, right?

Comment: Yes you are right @Shahin

Comment: :) so the paging is the answer, thanks to Leo.

Comment: Actually clipsToBounds was the key for me to achieve what I need. Thanks to Leo. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable paging, you will get the effect you are looking for, sans the smaller preview scroll.

One method to overcome this is to make the scrollview's frame smaller (290 points), and have its `clipsToBounds` property set to `NO` (so you get the preview of the next portion).

Another is to implement the scrollview's delegate method `- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset` and calculate where the scrollview should scroll according to velocity. The first method is simpler.

Comment: I tried setting clipsToBounds, the scrolling is working perfectly as I wanted but the next UITableViews arent shown or previewed.

Comment: @jeraldov Did you set it to `NO`?

Comment: My bad, didn't notice it was on YES. I set it to NO and worked.